# Build failure due to Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build, dependencies

when I tried to build my application, I got such messages and build failed. Anybody could resolve this??

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_for_testingCompile'.
>
> Could not resolve com.box:box-android-sdk:3.0.2. 
>      Required by:JetApplication:app:unspecified
>
> Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/box/box-android-sdk/3.0.2/box-android-sdk-3.0.2.pom'.
>
> Connection to http://web-proxy.com:8080 refused
>
> Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0.
>        Required by:JetApplication:app:unspecified
>
> Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okhttp/okhttp/2.5.0/okhttp-2.5.0.pom'.
>
> Connection to http://web-proxy.com:8080 refused

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Please clean build your application again try to build..

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the gradle.properties file, then done clean and build. now it is working normally...